# SSIS does not pull the whole source data rows

Tags: oracle, ssis

I've an SSIS package which has source as a Oracle view.

Select * From VwWrkf

When I execute it , I get only 3rd of the data. There is about 1.5mil rows. But there is about 450K that Tabular loads.

Any reason why thay could be?

Comment: Basically the question is then “a Select * from Table is not returning all the rows in Table”. There is no way to give an answer to this question without more information. 
Where do you detect the missing rows? Have you tried a data viewer just after the OLE DB Source? Have you tried a select count(*)?

Comment: @Jayvee When I Preview in OLEDB Source Editor Select count(*) from View - i get 450k rows which is a spreaded across all dates. But when i run the same query in Oracle Developer I get 1.5 Mil rows. When i say spreaded across all dates i mean - on Oracle Developer i see 1300 rows for 03/01/2012 but in SSIS preview i see 700 rows. There is no reasoning i can see why Oracle develeoper shows 1300 rows and SSIS preview shows 700.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the date format of a particular section of the report. It did something which Microsoft did not like.

[Related document could be found here](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2012/9/2/resolving-missing-records-in-ssis-from-oracle-source.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use fast load at destination OLEDB task which clears buffer faster and allow all records to process.  May be as the buffer getting filled and the records not processed it might not getting the rest of records and might be the connection timedout.

Comment: its not about loading it, when I preview count(*) at data source window it shows incorrect number of rows.

Answer (score -1):

It is nothing about "SSIS does not pull the whole source data rows".
If you preview the table data ,it shows only sample data right?.Likewise in the case with
select count(*) as well.If you can run the data flow,it would pick all the data form the source and will be loading it into target table.

If you still doubt,Instead of checking the ssis preview ,can you/is it possible to load data into a destination temp table,and check whether all the data being loaded into destination temp table

Comment: No - you are wrong. If i do count(*) it is not on sample data it is on whole list. I did transfer it to a destination table and that's where i saw the discrepancy. Please check the link i provided, it has the issue i'm talking about. Cheers